# Equals sign at end of filename

Tags: file, ls

I'm having some mysql trouble, and I went to find my mysql socket file but it has an equals sign appended to the end when doing `ls -lA` on the directory. I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8.

```
srwxrwxrwx  1 _mysql  wheel    0 Jul 23 10:08 mysql.sock=
```

When I `cat` it with the equals sign its a no go so it isn't really part of the name...

```
cat: mysql.sock=: No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? I can find a lot of info on line about `*` and `@` being appended, but not `=`

I guess I should note that when I cat it without the equals sign, it does work.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59132/what-does-the-d-mean-in-ls-al-results-and-what-is-that-slot-called) has helped me understand what the starting `s` means (it means 'socket').

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answer is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107429/sign-at-the-end-of-sock-files-in-the-ls-output

It just means socket.

Comment: For documentation of all `ls` classification symbols: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html